# Testing payments with Paypal SandBox

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

I've just signed up for a Paypal SandBox account but I can't figure out where to find the sandbox URL to send payments to? Only thing I can make out is that you can send IPN's to your IPN script from the paypal site, but can't do an actual real payment simulation from your site through to the paypal sandbox!?

Could anybody advise me here on where I can find the URL and/or if I can do what I want to do!?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redirect to `https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr` you can find more information in the documentation below:

https://www.x.com/sites/default/files/pp_sandbox_userguide.pdf

Comment: Thanks a lot! Though I think you made a typo, it's `webscr`, not `websrc` :)

Answer (score 1):

Below is an image with all of PayPal's other endpoints. The Sandbox user guide provided above is very useful as well. Let me know if you are having issues using a specific product and I can provide more information.

[image: API Endpoints]

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use Paypal SandBox to test your site and then connect to actual Paypal account. Paypal SandBox is working the same way as the actual Paypal.

To do this you have to call following APIs

1. SetExpressCheckout API
2. If the operation was successful send the token using this link. https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-binwebscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=EC-1NK66318YB717835M
3. GetExpressCheckoutDetails API
4. DoExpressCheckoutPayment API

Below link gives you step by step instruction about this:

[Testing PayPal Express Checkout](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_ECTesting)

Hope this helps